# Change of order size

Tags: market-microstructure, limit-order-book

For example I am put a limit order of size 10 at top bid.
moments later, my algorithm detects we should have size of 50 here. So we request a update on this order.

My question is, will we lose the current queue position due to this update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Increasing the size of an order is like cancelling and reinserting it. You lose queue priority and insert behind the other orders.

Comment: It depends on exactly which market we're talking about. But in general with price/time priority markets this is true.

Comment: @LouisMarascio, I wonder, is there any exchange that allows to keep the queue in this case?

Comment: What if my update action is actually to reduce the quantity?

Comment: You do not lose queue priority then. But check for the exchange and market you are interested in. This might differ from exchange to exchange and from market to market.